# errorTypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, json, strapi

I'm trying to use Strapi Headless CMS to create blog posts. I managed to fetch the JSON data but I'm unable to display it as HTML using the map() function. I want to display this data into the HTML but I keep getting this error. I already tried with a for loop and foreach() but I keep getting the same error like this or errorTypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data'). Here's my code so far:

```
 const blogPosts = "http://localhost:1337/api/blogposts";

fetch(blogPosts)
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
.then((data) => console.log(data.data[0].attributes))

.then((data) => {
  let posts = data;

  posts.map(function (post) {
    let body = document.createElement("div");

    body.innerHTML = `${post.data.data[0].attributes.body}`;
    li.appendChild(body);
  });
})

.catch(function (err) {
  console.log("error" + err);
});
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{data: Array(1)
     data: Array(1)
       0:
         attributes:
           body: "text"
           createdAt: "2022-02-11T10:29:48.930Z"
           publishedAt: "2022-02-11T10:29:58.780Z"
           updatedAt: "2022-02-11T10:29:58.790Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line:

```
body.innerHTML = `${post.data.data[0].attributes.body}`;
```

with:

```
body.innerHTML = `${post.data[0].attributes.body}`;
```

Comment: Still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

As error says, It is not able to read the `data` property as you are having only one `data` object in the response.

**Valid JSON :**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "attributes": {
            "body": "text",
            "createdAt": "2022-02-11T10:29:48.930Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-02-11T10:29:58.780Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-02-11T10:29:58.790Z"
        }
    }]
}
```

Hence, access it by calling `data[0].attributes.body` instead of `data.data[0].attributes.body`.

Comment: I can fetch it with data.data[0].attributes.body, because of the auto generated JSON

Comment: So what's the issue ?